# changing the style on a CFGRID

Tags: css, coldfusion, cfgrid, extjs

hey - the cfgrid (and other cf ui) stuff makes use of the EXT JS lib... does eny one know how to change the CF grid table header colors? and or the border colors? - In the HTML grid NOT the flash or applet... thx

Answer (score 0):

Customizing Look and Feel : Skin your ColdFusion 8 Ajax UI Components

http://www.rakshith.net/blog/?p=31

Comment: This appears to be a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

More style to pick for CF9 (Ext 2)

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/themes/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You can hack CF existing stylesheet as follow.

.x-grid-hd-text {
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.x-grid-row div{
line-height:16px;
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:13px;
}

.x-grid-col {
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:13px;
border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2010/9/16/change-font-in-cfgrid